# Passing variable in file path

Tags: java, vugen

I want to pass the timestamp variable in the filename variable. Please suggest how.
I am doing this in VUGEN.

Code:

```
int timestamp;
char * filename;


web_save_timestamp_param("c_launchid", LAST);

timestamp = lr_output_message( "%s",lr_eval_string("{c_launchid}") );

filename = "C:\\temp\\icafile_{timestamp}.ica";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Vugen, but normally in Java you could do it like so:

```
filename = String.format("C:\\temp\\icafile_{%d}.ica", timestamp);
```

Or perhaps a more simple approach:

```
filename = "C:\\temp\\icafile_{" + timestamp + "}.ica";
```